# pandas - problem with retrieve the data that extracted by using the unstack function fills null values with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have created the data frame like this

```
df_gr_1971 = df.where(df.year == 1971).groupby(['year', 'ID1', 'ID2']).size().unstack(fill_value='0')

list_all71 = [(list(i), v) for i, v in df_gr_1971.stack().iteritems()]
list_all71 = pd.DataFrame(list_all71, columns=["ID3", "count"])
list_all71

cols = ['year', 'ID1', 'ID2']
s = df.where(df.year == 1971).groupby(cols).size().unstack(fill_value='0').stack()

L = [{'year_1971': idx[0], 'ID3': list(idx[1:]), 'count': vals} for idx, vals in s.items()]
df_list_all71 = pd.DataFrame(L)

df_list_all71
```

the results have appeared like this

```
      ID3     count year_1971
0   [11, B6]    2   1971.0
1   [11, H1]    1   1971.0
2   [11, H2]    1   1971.0
3   [24, B6]    1   1971.0
4   [24, H1]    0   1971.0
```

when i want to show the rows that count == 0, i using this code

```
wsp_71 = df_list_all71[df_list_all71['count']==0]
wsp_71
```

but the result is being like this.

```
ID3 count   year
```

but i would like to see this result

```
    ID3   count year_1971
4   [24, H1]    0   1971.0
```

any ideas for solving this problem? or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem `fill_value='0'` - for non exist values is assign string `'0'`, so need:

```
.unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

Theoretically solution should be filtering by string `'0'`, but mixing numeric with strings is not recommended:

```
df_list_all71[df_list_all71['count']=='0']
```

Comment: Good recommendation +1

Comment: @pygo - Sorry, I was wrong, this behaviour was in some past versions of pandas ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if your suggested df looks like below:

```
>>> df
        ID3  count year_1971
0  [11, B6]      2    1971.0
1  [11, H1]      1    1971.0
2  [11, H2]      1    1971.0
3  [24, B6]      1    1971.0
4  [24, H1]      0    1971.0

>>> df[df['count']==0]
        ID3  count year_1971
4  [24, H1]      0    1971.0
```

Another trick with the above example:

```
>>> df.loc[(df==0).any(axis=1)]
        ID3  count year_1971
4  [24, H1]      0    1971.0
```

OR

```
>>> df[(df.T == 0).any()]
        ID3  count year_1971
4  [24, H1]      0    1971.0
>>> pd.__version__
'0.23.3'
```